# Bug ao executar programa no Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Estou com um problema ao criar o menu do jogo. O que acontece é que quando eu crio a função `draw_text`, o programa fica em tela preta e eu percebo que ele não mostra nada na tela fazendo com que nem feche a aba do mesmo.

Vou deixar o código para analisarem e falarem se foi algo de errado que eu fiz.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from sys import exit
import random

pygame.init()
fonte = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 20)

def sentings()->int:
    global largura, altura
    largura = 600
    altura = 450
    return largura, altura

def draw_text(text, font, color, surface, x, y):
    textobj = font.render(text, 1, color)
    textrect = textobj.get_rect()
    textrect.topleft = (x, y)
    surface.blit(textobj, textrect)



def menu():
    while True:
        tela = pygame.display.set_mode((sentings()))
        tela.fill((0, 0, 0))
        draw_text('Menu', fonte, (200, 200, 200), tela, 20, 20)

def main():
    global tela
    tela = pygame.display.set_mode((sentings()))
    pygame.display.set_caption('jogo')
    x = largura/2
    y = altura/2
    relogio = pygame.time.Clock()
    while True:
        menu()
        relogio.tick(30)
        tela.fill((0, 0, 0))

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()

        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_a]:
            x = x - 20
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_d]:
            x = x + 20
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_w]:
            y = y - 20
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_s]:
            y = y + 20

        choice = random.randint(100,250)
        red_ret = pygame.draw.rect((tela), (255, 0,0), (x,y, 40, 50))
        white_ret = pygame.draw.rect((tela), (200, 0, 0), (0, 0, 40, choice))

        pygame.display.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Qual é a função do `while True` na função `menu`?

Comment: apenas para chamar a função antes de entrar no jogo, tentei iniciar ela lá em baixo com o main, porém ela acusou outro bug diferente deste. onde a tela na aparecia o nome

Comment: Mas se tem um laço infinito, ela ficará sempre executando essa função e não executará o resto do código. Faz sentido isso?

Comment: não, porém não consigo colocar pra rodar esta função que criei.

Comment: Apenas remova o `while True` e o `tela.fill((0, 0, 0))` da função `menu()`. E coloque a linha em que você chama a função `menu()` após a linha `tela.fill((0, 0, 0))` dentro da função `main()`. O que você está fazendo é basicamente apagando o que foi escrito.

Comment: mesma coisa, nada mudou.